# Javascript OOP call method from args without eval

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to call a class method from arguments passed.
So far I have managed to get this working with eval.
I am hoping there is another way? as eval = evil :)

```
var myApi = (function() {

  var projects = {
    showDetails: function() {
      alert('from callMethod');
    }
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      $(window).on("resize", function() {
        introduction.fitContent(true);
      });
    },

    callMethod: function(obj, method) {

      return eval(obj+'.'+method+'()');
      //return projects.showDetails();
    },
  };

})();

$(function(){
  myApi.init();
});
```

From another file I can access var myApi
`myApi.callMethod('projects', 'showDetails');`

If possible I would also like to pass args to the method
`myApi.callMethod('projects', 'showDetails', {'page': 1, 'category', 'design'});`

This does not seem to be a duplicate post to me.
The class name & method is dynamic passed as arguments.

For example "projects" is just one of the class names.

Comment: You're looking for `apply`:  `obj[methodName].apply(obj, arguments)`

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this `obj[method].apply(obj, args);` and it comes up with an error "TypeError: obj[method] is undefined" The problem is I think it still sees obj as a string.

Comment: Small example: https://jsfiddle.net/sam3j6tL/

Comment: in your example you call "someObject" the problem is the object name needs to be dynamic. I have updated your jsfiddle which hopefully explains the issue further (https://jsfiddle.net/7p21zcv8/1/)

Comment: `object = window[objName]` if objects are global, or make these objects properties of some "super" object and use `object = superObj[objName].`

Comment: I have just found this which works but again uses eval
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14389485/ so it looks like eval is my only option for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102813/discussion-between-user828941-and-georg).